How to override <property> in AndroidManifest from an AAR in a module?
I have a base module, App.
Also have a on demand module, ads.
in my ads module, I include this google sdk com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:23.4.0
Now, looking at the merged AndoridManifest, i see the google sdk injected property
<application>
    ....
    <property
        android:name="android.adservices.AD_SERVICES_CONFIG"
        android:resource="@xml/gma_ad_services_config" />
</application>

My build fails because my App does not have access to stuff defined in AAR.
So I am thinking of creating an xml with same content but different name, and then make it so that it reads  @xml/gma_ad_services_config_override instead.
However, I tried adding these to both my App AndroidManifest, as well as in the submodule AndroidManifest.
<application>
    ....
    <property android:name="android.adservices.AD_SERVICES_CONFIG"
        android:resource="@xml/gma_ad_services_config_override"
        tools:node="replace" />
</application>


Neither has changed the merged android manifest. What's the correct way to override it?
